# How to add data dynamically in JSON object

Tags: json

Sample code

```
var mydata = [ {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}];
```

I have to get output something like above, have to add dynamically columns and its value to mydata.

I am trying to do something like this but its not working for me.

```
var mydata = [];
for (var r = 0; r < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); r++) {
  var items = "";
  var y ="";
   for (var c = 0; c < dataTable.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
     items += '"'+dataTable.getColumnLabel(c)+'":'+dataTable.getValue(r, c)
      if(c!=dataTable.getNumberOfColumns()-1){
        items += ",";
      }
   }
   y = "{"+items+"}";
   mydata.push(y);
}
```

above code doesnt works for me. any other way for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy:

`oldJsonObj.vector = [] //this creates a new element into the object`

```
foreach(dataTable.getNumberOfRows()){
  var x = {}
  x.id = XXX;
  x.name = XXX;
  oldJsonObj.vector.push(x); //adds the element x to array
}

alert(oldJsonObj.vector[i].name); //easy accses
```

Answer (score 5):

Hope this can help you:

```
var json = []; 

// add an field 'a'
json['a'] = 1;
alert(json["a"]);  //1 

// add an field 'b'
json['b'] = []; // another json object
...
```

in your case:

```
mydata=[];

// add json fields
mydata["id"] = 1;
mydata["invdate"] = "2007-10-01";
mydata["name"] = "test";
//...
```

Comment: thanks Soony, but I did not follow how the above will work. I have to add "a" or "b" or "c" and its value dynamically to json

Comment: are you suggesting me to do something like this

Comment: `for (var r = 0; r < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); r++) 
     `{
      `for (var c = 0; c < dataTable.getNumberOfColumns(); c++)
       `{
          `mydata[dataTable.getColumnLabel(c)] = dataTable.getValue(r, c);
       `}
    `}


It didnt worked out as I need output some thing like this.


    `var mydata = [ 
         {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},         {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}
    ];`